# is there any way to automatically export reports to testrail?

Tags: integration, testrail, reportportal

I would like to export test data from RP to testrail automatically.
I have found the following issue but without any information on how it was solved or why was this closed. Would be happy to any guidance on how to set it up.
https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal/issues/145